# How to write the name of a function using a function pointer?

Tags: c, function-pointers

I have this code with an array of function pointers that represents a sequence of functions, and I want to display the function names like this:

```
static void print_sequence(t_op_sequence *seq)
{
    int i;

    i = -1;
    while (++i < seq->size)
    {
        if (seq->sequence[i] == pa)
            ft_putendl("pa");
        else if (seq->sequence[i] == pb)
            ft_putendl("pb");
        else if (seq->sequence[i] == sa)
            ft_putendl("sa");
        else if (seq->sequence[i] == sb)
            ft_putendl("sb");
        else if (seq->sequence[i] == ss)
            ft_putendl("ss");
        else if (seq->sequence[i] == ra)
            ft_putendl("ra");
        else if (seq->sequence[i] == rb)
            ft_putendl("rb");
        else if (seq->sequence[i] == rr)
            ft_putendl("rr");
        else if (seq->sequence[i] == rra)
            ft_putendl("rra");
        else if (seq->sequence[i] == rrb)
            ft_putendl("rrb");
        else if (seq->sequence[i] == rrr)
            ft_putendl("rrr");
    }
}
```

The `t_op_sequence` struct containing a flexible function pointer array:

```
typedef void    (*t_operation)(t_stack *, t_stack *);

typedef struct  s_op_sequence
{
    size_t      size;
    t_operation sequence[];
}   t_op_sequence;
```

There is no problem with my code but I'd like to do it without all the `if/else` or `switch` statements. I know that inside a function you can use `__func__` or `__FUNCTION__` to get the function's name, but is there a trick to do the same but using function pointers, so outside of the function itself?

Comment: Not really; you have to have an `if` sequence, or create a hash table and code to search it,  or something like that.  You can streamline the process with a macro using stringification, so that all you have to write is `X(pa); X(pb); ...`

Comment: No, there isn't a way to map function pointers to function names built-in with standard C.  An array mapping pointers to names is one to do it; an `if`/`else` chain like you show is another.

Comment: Btw `switch` won't work either; the `case`s have to be integer constants, and addresses, even addresses of functions or globals, don't count.

Comment: Could you create a struct containing two fields: a function name in a string as well and a pointer to the function? Using that approach simply call the function through the pointer and output the associated name.

Comment: You might have an answer, but **how did you set your function pointers in the first place**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contrary to what people say in answers and comments, it is indeed possible.

Here is a creative approach:

- Change your function signature from returning `void` to returning `const char*`.
- Change the functions themselves to return their name as `const char*` string when both arguments are null pointers.
- Call the functions with null pointers as arguments
- Profit!

Comment: I'll just tweak something: let the function prototyped `void` and directly print the name instead of returning it when called with`NULL`

Comment: @Fayeure this is up to you, if your app allows this, than it is easier.

Comment: @Fayeure, @SergeyA you could even avoid changing the return type. Just change the arguments to `void    (t_stack *, t_stack *,...)`. Next use `va_list` interface to parse implicit `char**` argument if both `t_stack` arguments are `NULL`. Store `__FUNCTION__` to via pointer with the implicit argument.

Comment: @tstanisl that would certainly work too, but I find it slightly harder to implement (va_list IS convoluted) than changing return type.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible in general.

The closest thing you can do is to use macros to generate that sequence of `if`s without having to repeat each name twice.

Comment: Surely it is possible, see my answer.